# Android randomly generate equation answer

Tags: java, android, math

I am creating a program where there is randomly generated numbers and randomly generated operands depending on the difficulty the user has chosen. I have done the random part for numbers and operands but can't figure out how to work out the answers. Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks.

```
   public void generateNumbers(int diff) {

    switch (diff) {


        // Novice difficulty
        case 0:
            Random r = new Random();
            Random x = new Random();
            Random RandomOperand = new Random();
            oper = operands[RandomOperand.nextInt(operands.length)];
            Log.d("Brain Trainer", "operand = " + oper);
            equation.setText("  " + r.nextInt(200) + " " + oper + " " + x.nextInt(200) + " =" + " ?");
            break;
        // Easy difficulty
        case 1:
            Random ran = new Random();
            int p = ran.nextInt(2);
            Log.d("Brain Trainer", "Random num = " + p);
            switch (p) {
                case 0:
                    r = new Random();
                    x = new Random();
                    RandomOperand = new Random();
                    oper = operands[RandomOperand.nextInt(operands.length)];
                    equation.setText("  " + r.nextInt(200) + " " + oper + " " + x.nextInt(200) + " =" + " ?");
                    break;

                case 1:
                    r = new Random();
                    x = new Random();
                    Random z = new Random();
                    RandomOperand = new Random();
                    oper = operands[RandomOperand.nextInt(operands.length)];
                    oper1 = operands[RandomOperand.nextInt(operands.length)];
                    equation.setText("  " + r.nextInt(200) + " " + oper + " " + x.nextInt(200) + " " + oper1 + " " + z.nextInt(200) + " =" + " ?");
                    break;
            }
            break;
        //Medium difficulty
        case 2:
            ran = new Random();
            p = ran.nextInt(3);
            Log.d("Brain Trainer", "Random num = " + p);
            switch (p) {
                case 0:
                    r = new Random();
                    x = new Random();

                    RandomOperand = new Random();
                    oper = operands[RandomOperand.nextInt(operands.length)];
                    equation.setText("  " + r.nextInt(200) + " " + oper + " " + x.nextInt(200) + " =" + " ?");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    r = new Random();
                    x = new Random();
                    Random z = new Random();
                    RandomOperand = new Random();
                    oper = operands[RandomOperand.nextInt(operands.length)];
                    oper1 = operands[RandomOperand.nextInt(operands.length)];
                    equation.setText("  " + r.nextInt(200) + " " + oper + " " + x.nextInt(200) + " " + oper1 + " " + z.nextInt(200) + " =" + " ?");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    r = new Random();
                    x = new Random();
                    z = new Random();
                    Random c = new Random();
                    RandomOperand = new Random();
                    oper = operands[RandomOperand.nextInt(operands.length)];
                    oper1 = operands[RandomOperand.nextInt(operands.length)];
                    oper2 = operands[RandomOperand.nextInt(operands.length)];
                    equation.setText("  " + r.nextInt(200) + " " + oper + " " + x.nextInt(200) + " " + oper1 + " " + z.nextInt(200) + " " + oper2 + " " + c.nextInt(200) + " =" + " ?");
                    break;
            }
            break;

        // Guru difficulty
        case 3:
            ran = new Random();
            p = ran.nextInt(3);
            Log.d("Brain Trainer", "Random num = " + p);
            switch (p) {
                case 0:
                    r = new Random();
                    x = new Random();
                    Random z = new Random();
                    Random c = new Random();
                    RandomOperand = new Random();
                    oper = operands[RandomOperand.nextInt(operands.length)];
                    oper1 = operands[RandomOperand.nextInt(operands.length)];
                    oper2 = operands[RandomOperand.nextInt(operands.length)];
                    equation.setText("  " + r.nextInt(200) + " " + oper + " " + x.nextInt(200) + " " + oper1 + " " + z.nextInt(200) + " " + oper2 + " " + c.nextInt(200) + " =" + " ?");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    r = new Random();
                    x = new Random();
                    z = new Random();
                    c = new Random();
                    Random v = new Random();
                    RandomOperand = new Random();
                    oper = operands[RandomOperand.nextInt(operands.length)];
                    oper1 = operands[RandomOperand.nextInt(operands.length)];
                    oper2 = operands[RandomOperand.nextInt(operands.length)];
                    oper3 = operands[RandomOperand.nextInt(operands.length)];
                    equation.setText("  " + r.nextInt(200) + " " + oper + " " + x.nextInt(200) + " " + oper1 + " " + z.nextInt(200) + " " + oper2 + " " + c.nextInt(200) + oper3 + " "
                            + v.nextInt(200) + " =" + " ?");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    r = new Random();
                    x = new Random();
                    z = new Random();
                    c = new Random();
                    v = new Random();
                    Random h = new Random();
                    RandomOperand = new Random();
                    oper = operands[RandomOperand.nextInt(operands.length)];
                    oper1 = operands[RandomOperand.nextInt(operands.length)];
                    oper2 = operands[RandomOperand.nextInt(operands.length)];
                    oper3 = operands[RandomOperand.nextInt(operands.length)];
                    oper4 = operands[RandomOperand.nextInt(operands.length)];
                    equation.setText("  " + r.nextInt(200) + " " + oper + " " + x.nextInt(200) + " " + oper1 + " " + z.nextInt(200) + " " + oper2 + " " + c.nextInt(200) + " " +
                            " " + oper3 + " " + v.nextInt(200) + " " + oper4 + v.nextInt(200) + " =" + " ?");
                    break;
            }
            break;

    }
}
```

Comment: Just save your random generated numbers and perform the operation.

Comment: Once you have chosen the numbers and operators, just do the calculation. You will need a different piece of code for each operator.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever the equation you have generated, you might need to store the result of that expression as a data member of the particular class in the following way:

With JDK1.6+ you can use the built in Javascript Engine. e.g.,

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;

public class App{
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
    ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager ();
    ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
    System.out.println(engine.eval("2+2"));
  }
}
```